# "specified" or "specific"

Tags: word-usage

In my other post (["Wild animals" or "The wild animals"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240193/109190)) I said

> ... where she uses the in her beginning, which seems to be incorrect. Because what the question mentions is not a **specified** group of wild animals, neither the beginning of Alice's answer.

where I used "**specified**". Actually I am not sure if I used the right word. Another option is **specific**.

Cambridge Dictionary gives this definition about **specific**.

> relating to one thing and not others; particular

**specified** is the past participle form and therefor probably able to used as adjective here.

Are **specific** and **specified** interchangeable in this case?

Comment: I hope this will help you: https://www.quora.com/When-should-I-use-the-word-specific-vs-specified

>> specified
when you want to use the past tense or the past participle of the verb 'to specify'

specific
when you want to use an adjective meaning
1. clearly defined or identified. or
2. of, relating to, or connected with species or a species. (biology)
or as a noun meaning
1. a precise detail. or
2. a medicine or remedy effective in treating a particular disease or part of the body.